# Can I just visit social media sites like I would in my previous life

Tags: login

I am trying to understand Tor with respect to 'everday browsing'. For example, I'm not sure I understand the answers to [this question regarding logging into Facebook](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/if-i-log-into-facebook-with-tor-am-i-still-protected).

I understand that if I have a Facebook account with real name etc., I am not anonymous *to Facebook* once I log in, no matter whether I use Tor or not. But using Facebook from the Tor browser will still protect my anonymity to servers outside of Facebook, right?

Should I always keep a second normal browser open to use Facebook or can I do this in the Tor browser without compromising my privacy (on any other site I visit)?

Or put differently, can I just substitute my regular browser with the Tor browser without becoming entirely religious or a zealous vegan about my normal browsing habits. Do I have develop a paranoid browsing behavior or can I just visit the social media sites like before?

Answer (score 1):

Tor is about hiding who you are, not what you do. Unless you are using end-to-end encryption, someone who is listening can see what you do. That is why logging into Facebook is a bad idea -it deanonymizes you for the potential listener.

> Should I always keep a second normal browser open to use Facebook or
>   can I do this in the Tor browser without compromising my privacy (on
>   any other site I visit)?

You can do this, but there are potential risks. [Cookie extraction](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/12/nsa_tracks_peop.html) and [timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) being two of them. I wouldn't worry about it too much though.

> Or put differently, can I just substitute my regular browser with the
>   Tor browser without becoming entirely religious or a zealous vegan
>   about my normal browsing habits.

You can, but the question is why you would want to do that. Tor is not really fit for day-to-day browsing.. You will leak personal information.